# Is there a way to remove a list-item (or grouping) from a dictionary in Ansible jsonfacts file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I was able to merge 2 lists together using the following in my test.yml file:

```
        set_fact:
            connectors: "{{containerports | default([]) }} + {{ newportslist }}"
```

which produced the following in my custom facts JSON file:

```
{
"containerports": [
    {
        "containername": "two", 
        "local_port_file": "10502", 
        "local_port_stream": "11502", 
    }, 
    {
        "containername": "five", 
        "local_port_file": "10503", 
        "local_port_stream": "11503", 
    }
]
}
```

Is there a way in Ansible that I can remove a a whole list{}? And if there is, is there a way to remove it based off of a field name?

Ideally, I would have something like "remove list that has a containername called "five" which would then update my facts file to be:

```
{
"containerports": [
    {
        "containername": "two", 
        "local_port_file": "10502", 
        "local_port_stream": "11502", 
    } 
]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [Jinja Filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html). Filters provide all sorts of methods of manipulating data. A common filter used for dealing with lists of dictionaries is the `selectattr` filter, which will extract a dictionary from a list, based on some attribute. There is a corresponding `rejectattr`, that extracts anything that does not match. Therefore try this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    exclude_name: "two"
    containerports:
      - containername: "two" 
        local_port_file: "10502" 
        local_port_stream: "11502"
      - containername: "three" 
        local_port_file: "10503" 
        local_port_stream: "11503"
      - containername: "four" 
        local_port_file: "10504" 
        local_port_stream: "11504"
  tasks:
    - name: Extract all but dictionary called <exclude_name>
      set_fact:
        containerports: "{{ containerports | rejectattr('containername', 'match', exclude_name) | list }}"
    - name: Display the result
      debug:
        var: containerports
```

Results in:

```
TASK [Display the result] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "containerports": [
        {
            "containername": "three", 
            "local_port_file": "10503", 
            "local_port_stream": "11503"
        }, 
        {
            "containername": "four", 
            "local_port_file": "10504", 
            "local_port_stream": "11504"
        }
    ]
}
```